# Is Deadpool 2's after-credits scene canon or just a joke?

Tags: ending, x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool-2

In the end of *Deadpool 2*, Deadpool receives the time machine of Cable, modified to be used multiple times. Then he actually saves Vanessa's life with it, among other things.

Did he actually do this? Does that mean she is still alive and will participate in *Deadpool 3*? Or is it just some post credits fun?

Comment: Isn't the whole movie a joke?

Comment: @jpmc26 Is real life a joke?

Comment: @Möoz According to The Life Of Brian, yes. "Life's a laugh and death's a joke, it's true."

Answer (score 56, accepted):

That post-credit scene is **CANON** as the [writers said during their reddit AMA](https://www.reddit.com/r/movies/comments/8keylr/we_are_rhett_reese_and_paul_wernick_cowriters_and/dz747dz/):

> Q: IS THE AFTER CREDIT SCENE CANON??? Please tell me I’m dying to know!
>   A: Yes, the after credit scene is CANON! Don't expect that device to stick around beyond this movie, though!

So yes, Vanessa is alive and *in a universe that is beautiful and just*, Green Lantern movie and mouth-shut-pool does not exist...

Comment: Didn't see the quote, but this is what I figured (simply via the logic that making it canon gives the writers more options, and takes none away. In a fictional universe, the writers always win.) However, stating this officially does beg the question of why doesn't he hand the fixed device back to Cable when he's done with it, and allow the poor guy to go back home?

Comment: Does that mean the entire Deadpool 2 movie didn't happen? If Vanessa never dies, Wade doesn't try to kill himself, doesn't get dragged to the X-Men by Colossus, doesn't go on that mission as a trainee, doesn't get arrested and try to save Russell in jail. So Cable just succeeds in killing him and goes home? So Deadpool 2 NEVER HAPPENED!?

Comment: @JunKang In which case Deadpool never gets Cable's time machine and never saves Vanessa. And anyways Cable never came back because his family didn't die. I think maybe it's in the after credit scene so we don't ask too many questions about plot holes and time travel.

Comment: @JackArbiter I mean if the writers specifically confirm it being canon, they cant expect people not to ask questions. #Deadpool2Paradox

Comment: I think canonically their time travel doesn't work that way; the Teddy Bear changed but Cable still was back in time, why would it work differently when Deadpool does it? The bigger plot hole I see is that the way it works is inconsistent: you can go back in time with your current self (when Cable comes back initially), and also go back in time to replace the memories of yourself at that time (Cable does this to save Deadpool, and that's how the time travel works in the first after-credits scene). Anyway, it's deadpool. I don't think it's meant to be perfect.

Comment: Consider it as Deadpool's flashpoint AKA deadpoint/poolpoint? He just changed Vanessa's living status and the moustache man's too... Evrything else occured as per the movie. Perhaps instead of Deadpool moping around as X-men trainee, he could have happilly taken the job. That might be the difference... Or his screw-up might be the plot of DP3 or X-force...

Comment: @JunKang Of course it never happened. It's just a film, it's not real life `:P`

Comment: @Pharap - oh ... oh, not real life ... Wait, WHAT!

Comment: What about the deleted end credits scene?  You know, the one where he went back and offed an Austrian?

Comment: @JunKang I think Austin and Basil have the best advice for trying to figure out timetravel in movies: https://youtu.be/x8w95xIdH4o?t=25